# How to close the form if the user press sign out in c#

Tags: c#

I've a bug on my program here. When the user want to sign out, the form or forms cannot closed automatically. I've call it to closed with if syntax but it cannot do it. My programming language is Microsoft visual studio C# 2010 and using windows form option.

NB. I don't want to close the entire form.. I just want to close the children form.

This is what I've done.

**This is a code to call the forms**

```
registerForm rgs;
loginForm lgn;
masterCarForm mcf;
manageEmployeeForm mef;
rentForm rf;
bookingRentForm brf;
viewRentForm vrf;
reviewForm refo;
```

**This is the sign out code**

```
private void SMCsignOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SMPstaffMenu.Visible == true)
    {
        if ((mcf != null && !mcf.IsDisposed) || (mef != null && !mef.IsDisposed) || (rf != null && !rf.IsDisposed))
        {
            mcf.Hide();
            mef.Hide();
            rf.Hide();
            SMClogin.Visible = true;
            SMCsignOut.Visible = false;
            SMPstaffMenu.Visible = false;
            SMPservice.Visible = false;
            SMCregister.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (brf != null && !brf.IsDisposed && vrf != null && !vrf.IsDisposed && refo != null && !refo.IsDisposed)
            {
                brf.Hide();
                vrf.Hide();
                refo.Hide();
                SMClogin.Visible = true;
                SMCsignOut.Visible = false;
                SMPstaffMenu.Visible = false;
                SMPservice.Visible = false;
                SMCregister.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what should i do here.. Thanks..

Comment: In your code you only hide windows (i.e. call `Hide()`), but this will not actually close the windows (and therefor leave the application running). When you want to close a window in Windows Forms, then you'll have to call the `Close()` method. Alternatively you could try to just call `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()` to close all currently opened windows.

Comment: no.. i'm not want to class the entire windows.. i just want to close the childs form.. @bassfader

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Form.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx)?

In windows forms, using Form.Close (in this case, I suppose when pressing the "Sign Out" button), should close the child form, instead of hiding it like it was in your code.

Comment: no.. if application.exit, it will close the mdiparent form.. i just want to close the child form

Comment: @YosuaChristianov Are you closing the child form from within the child form? Or from the parent form?

Comment: i have home form which is has 6 child.. so, i want to close that six not the home form @tmello01

Comment: @YosuaChristianov In your code you are using `brf.Hide()` if you want the child form to be closed, you should change the `.Hide()` to `.Close()`

Comment: if i use your suggest, i've been already used it.. but in EXIT button not on the Sign out button..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywwXmd4D1rDaDFJODVWUnNpUFk that's my error @tmello01